# How to make a search from the position of cursor and select if I want to do it from that position to up or down

Tags: python, select, search, text, tkinter

I'm coding a text editor as part of my learning Python. I can search the text in Text Widget from an Entry Widget with this piece of code bellow, but need how to make a search from the position of cursor and select if I want to do it from that position to up or down, I don't  know how to do that.

I could add a Radiobutton for (up option) and other for (down option) just like Notepad in Windows, but I need the code to do that. Does anyone know?

And my code doesn't differentiate between upper case and lower case, I don´t know why.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as MessageBox

search_list = list()
s = ""

def reset_list():
    if s != entry_widget_name.get():
        search_list.clear()
        text_widget_name.tag_remove(SEL, 1.0,"end-1c")

def search_words():
    reset_list()
    global search_list
    global s
    text_widget_name.focus_set()
    s = entry_widget_name.get()

    if s:
        if search_list == []:
            idx = "1.0"
        else:
            idx = search_list[-1]

        idx = text_widget_name.search(s, idx, nocase=1, stopindex=END)
        lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len(s))

        try:
            text_widget_name.tag_remove(SEL, 1.0,lastidx)
        except:
            pass

        try:
            text_widget_name.tag_add(SEL, idx, lastidx)
            counter_list = []
            counter_list = str(idx).split('.')      
            text_widget_name.mark_set("insert", "%d.%d" % (float(int(counter_list[0])), float(int(counter_list[1]))))
            text_widget_name.see(float(int(counter_list[0])))
            search_list.append(lastidx)
        except:
            MessageBox.showinfo("Search complete","No further matches")
            search_list.clear()
            text_widget_name.tag_remove(SEL, 1.0,"end-1c")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("540x460")

lbl_frame_entry = LabelFrame(root, text="Enter the text to search", padx=5, pady=5)
lbl_frame_entry.pack(padx=10, pady=5, fill="both")

entry_widget_name = Entry(lbl_frame_entry, width=50, justify = "left")
entry_widget_name.pack(fill="both")

lbl_frame_text = LabelFrame(root, text="Enter the text here", padx=5, pady=5, height=260)
lbl_frame_text.pack(padx=10, pady=5, fill="both", expand=True)

text_widget_name = Text(lbl_frame_text)
text_widget_name.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(text_widget_name, orient="vertical", command=text_widget_name.yview, cursor="arrow")
scrollbar.pack(fill="y", side="right")
text_widget_name.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

button_name = Button(root, text="Search", command=search_words, padx=5, pady=5)
button_name.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your search is not case sensitive because you use the option `nocase=1`. Just set it to False to get case sensitivity.

Comment: @j_4321 Thanks! Yes I already tried and works. And your answer below was completely useful. You will be in the special thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your search is not case sensitive because you used the option `nocase=1`.

Secondly, if you want to do a up or down search, there are the backwards and forwards options (I found the documentation [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-methods.html)). When you do a backward search, you also need to change the way you move the insert cursor too and the `stopindex`. Here is an example in which the text in the entry is searched in the text starting from the current insert position and moving upward / downward depending on the selected radiobutton:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as MessageBox

def search():
    pattern = e.get()
    if search_dir.get() == 'forwards':
        res = txt.search(pattern, 'insert', forwards=True, stopindex='end')
    else:
        res = txt.search(pattern, 'insert', backwards=True, stopindex='1.0')
    txt.tag_remove('sel', '1.0', 'end')
    try:
        txt.tag_add('sel', res, '%s+%ic' % (res, len(pattern)))
        if search_dir.get() == 'forwards':
            txt.mark_set('insert', '%s+%ic' % (res, len(pattern)))
        else:
            txt.mark_set('insert', '%s-1c' % (res))
    except:
        MessageBox.showinfo("Search complete","No further matches")


root = Tk()

txt = Text(root)
txt.pack(fill='both',expand=True)

e = Entry(root)
e.pack(fill='x')
search_dir = StringVar(root, 'forwards')  
Radiobutton(root, text='▲', value='backwards', variable=search_dir).pack()
Radiobutton(root, text='▼', value='forwards', variable=search_dir).pack()
Button(root, text='Search', command=search).pack()

root.mainloop()
```